# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass in update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Audi model in my ruby on rails application in which there are many fields like model, variant, car image, exterior, interior, brochure etc. When I try to update some attributes(not all), then it gives undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass in exterior and interior image section.

More specifically, the issue is here:

```
params[:exterior_image].each { |exterior_image| ... }
```

update method:

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      @audi_model = AudiModel.find(params[:id])
      if @audi_model.update(audi_model_params)
            model_exterior_image_names = @audi_model.car_exterior_images.map{|m|m.exterior_image_file_name}
            params[:exterior_image].each { |exterior_image|
            unless model_exterior_image_names.include?(exterior_image.original_filename)
            @audi_model.car_exterior_images.create(exterior_image: exterior_image)
            end
            }
            model_interior_image_names = @audi_model.car_interior_images.map{|m|m.interior_image_file_name}
            params[:interior_image].each { |interior_image|
            unless model_interior_image_names.include?(interior_image.original_filename)
            @audi_model.car_interior_images.create(interior_image: interior_image)
            end
            }
        format.html { redirect_to @audi_model, notice: 'Audi model was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @audi_model }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @audi_model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
```

Request
parameters :

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"3qiq/VNRNk369HEZr0Eb/R5iuhKgGTpJCfOh8ek3nGWLeU+zDNDvEAwJ3SvlLb0h4gVql549d3GnCV9Fa/ZnNA==",
 "audi_model"=>{"car_model"=>"TT",
 "variant"=>"Diesel",
 "introduction"=>"test",
 "engine"=>"test",
 "video_url"=>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3x_RZlOmK0",
 "brochure_url"=>"http://www.audigurgaon.in/brochure/tt-brochure-2014.pdf"},
 "commit"=>"Update Audi model",
 "id"=>"19"}
```

Comment: Inspect the `params` coming to the update action and post it in the question.

Comment: Can you post the form you use to update your model ? Also, add a "raise" at the beginning of the method, and type "params" to see what's being passed. Post here the params

Comment: audi model in one table which contains all the above parameters and there are two foreign key tables i.e. exterior images and exterior images. So i am trying to update the parameters in audi model table but not exterior and interior

Comment: Well, there is no `:exterior_image` in the `params` hash. That explains the error.

Comment: yes because i don't want to update exterior image. only few parameters to update

Comment: It's not possible if you don't have something in your params to use it ...... You call params[:exterior_image] but there isn't so it won't work.

Comment: And one thing it actually updates few parameters but shows this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `params` doesn't have `:exterior_image` key, so it would return `nil`. You have to check to make sure there `params[:exterior_image]` is not nil and only then call `.each` method on it.

```
params[:exterior_image].each do |exterior_image|
    unless model_exterior_image_names.include?(exterior_image.original_filename)
        @audi_model.car_exterior_images.create(exterior_image: exterior_image)
    end
end if params[:exterior_image]
```

Alternatively, give it an empty array:

```
(params[:exterior_image] || []).each do |exterior_image|
    unless model_exterior_image_names.include?(exterior_image.original_filename)
        @audi_model.car_exterior_images.create(exterior_image: exterior_image)
    end
end
```